# Add column to a dataframe for each value in a vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector

I have a vector (list) and a dataframe (df). I need to add a new column to this dataframe for each entry in the vector. I need these added columns to have the names of the given entries in the vector.

I've tried:

```
for(i in list)
{
    df<-cbind(df, i)
}
```

and

```
for(i in list)
{
    df[,i]<-NA
}
```

both return:
"Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1"
How should I go about this?

Comment: any sample data would help

Answer (score 0):

simply do

```
merge(df, as.list(list), by = NULL)
```

---

Example:

```
vec <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
df <- head(iris)
merge(df, as.list(vec))

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species a b c
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 1 2 3
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 1 2 3
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 1 2 3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 1 2 3
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 1 2 3
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use base subsetting with brackets `[` and the `names` of the `list` vector as the index

```
df[names(list)] <- NA
```

this would add columns with the same names as the elements from the named vectors.
We can not (should be cautious about) add the actual vector elements as these are length-1 objects, whereas the data.frame is likely longer. Indeed, this solution actually adds a single element that is recycled.